# How to clear memory from pictures of previous layouts? How to clean memory when go to different layout/activity?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio, out-of-memory

My app consists from 4 layout files, each layout uses a different image as background. I manage to load layout 1 and 2, but after I go to layout 3 I get error "Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError"

I suspect it's because the layout 1 and layout 2 is still in the memory. Any way is there a way to clean memory everytime I go to a new layout so I don't run out of memory? Thanks.

P.S I use Android Studio.

P.S 2 I'm not sure if this changes anything but just in case this is how I go to different activities/layouts:

```
previouspage.setOnClickListener(
                new Button.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), secondPage.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }
        );

        nextpage.setOnClickListener(
                new Button.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), FourthPage.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }
        );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
new Button.OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(View v) {
         Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), secondPage.class);
         startActivity(intent);

         yourExistingActivity.finish();  // This will free the memory

}
```

Note that the activity you're calling the finish() method from is destroyed and **ALL** its resources are **queued** for garbage collection, and all memory that was used by this activity will be freed during **next GC cycle**.

If you really want to revoke the memory **as soon as possible**, override your activities' onDestroy method:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Runtime.getRuntime().gc();      
}
```