# Killing Activity in Android studio

Tags: android

I am Newbie to Android Programming.I just got an issue regarding killing an Activity in android studio. How can I kill a certain activity (e.g. In my app i have two activities A and B.I want to kill activity B by clicking a button in activity A)
Can anyone Help me...

Comment: Why do you want to kill an `Activity` that may not have been created yet? If you want to kill `Activity B` after navigating back to `Activity A` then you can just set `android:noHistory="true"` in the `manifest.xml` for that `activity`

Comment: handle this stuff in `ActivityB`  on Event evey Activity have like  `onStop` or `onResume`

Comment: check the answer here:[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10379134/finish-an-activity-from-another-activity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10379134/finish-an-activity-from-another-activity)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever possible, I would try to avoid static references to other activities and use a `BroadcastReceiver` instead:

```
private final class FinishReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_FINISH)) 
            finish();
    }
}
```

Close by sending:

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(ACTION_FINISH));
```

Check the complete example in my earlier [post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18225393/clear-activity-back-stack).

Answer (score 0):

You can call this:

```
activityB.finish();
```

Comment: `Actirvity.finish()` does not guarantee 100% its gonna kill the `activity` you can read Docs and make sure of it

Comment: You are right, but this might be a little bit off topic. A relevant answer to really kill an activity can be found in my answers to these questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37028787/android-ondestroy-and-finish/37028970#37028970 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36928759/how-to-clear-memory-from-pictures-of-previous-layouts-how-to-clean-memory-when/36928785#36928785

Answer (score 0):

You can directly call the activity's `finish()` method to kill it.
`activity.finish()`

I would suggest looking into Activity life cycles to get a better understanding of what exactly you are doing.

For a solid reference: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html

Comment: If you found this answer helpful enough for your issue, please mark it as answered. :)